# Minikube node not ready after running skaffold dev - happens repeatedly

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, minikube, skaffold

I'm running skaffold dev and minikube keeps getting stuck.

I can stop and start minikube and it generally recovers.

Is the warning ContainerGCFailed the issue, or should I be investigating:

`PLEG is not healthy: pleg was last seen active 4m19.322678359s ago; threshold is 3m0s`

```
$ kubectl describe nodes
Name:               minikube
Roles:              master
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=minikube
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    minikube.k8s.io/commit=23f40a012abb52eff365ff99a709501a61ac5876
                    minikube.k8s.io/name=minikube
                    minikube.k8s.io/updated_at=2020_11_18T14_29_40_0700
                    minikube.k8s.io/version=v1.15.1
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Wed, 18 Nov 2020 14:29:37 +1100
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  minikube
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Wed, 18 Nov 2020 14:37:01 +1100
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Wed, 18 Nov 2020 14:36:56 +1100   Wed, 18 Nov 2020 14:29:35 +1100   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Wed, 18 Nov 2020 14:36:56 +1100   Wed, 18 Nov 2020 14:29:35 +1100   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Wed, 18 Nov 2020 14:36:56 +1100   Wed, 18 Nov 2020 14:29:35 +1100   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            False   Wed, 18 Nov 2020 14:36:56 +1100   Wed, 18 Nov 2020 14:35:45 +1100   KubeletNotReady              PLEG is not healthy: pleg was last seen active 4m19.322678359s ago; threshold is 3m0s
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  192.168.99.103
  Hostname:    minikube
Capacity:
  cpu:                4
  ephemeral-storage:  14777356Ki
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             16419284Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                4
  ephemeral-storage:  14777356Ki
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             16419284Ki
  pods:               110
System Info:
  Kernel Version:             4.19.150
  OS Image:                   Buildroot 2020.02.7
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://19.3.13
  Kubelet Version:            v1.19.4
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.19.4
Non-terminated Pods:          (22 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                                   CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                   ----                                                   ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                     aerospike-aerospike-enterprise-0                       0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6m6s
  default                     confluent-platform-cp-kafka-0                          0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6m8s
  default                     confluent-platform-cp-kafka-1                          0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6m6s
  default                     confluent-platform-cp-kafka-2                          0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5m51s
  default                     confluent-platform-cp-kafka-connect-57b789f97-sc4nf    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6m8s
  default                     confluent-platform-cp-zookeeper-0                      0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6m8s
  default                     dnsutils                                               0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5m59s
  default                     redis-master-0                                         0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6m3s
  default                     redis-slave-0                                          0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6m3s
  default                     redis-slave-1                                          0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5m25s
  default                     tellus-api-gateway-787f7574bd-s5pbm                    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5m59s
  default                     tellus-config-server-5f666967bc-s5dvq                  0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5m59s
  default                     tellus-gateway-message-service-789766f9c8-6ws7w        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5m59s
  default                     tellus-query-5954799f46-lgq9z                          0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5m58s
  default                     tellus-web-64c6cc884b-smv2s                            0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5m58s
  kube-system                 coredns-f9fd979d6-jclvd                                100m (2%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (1%)     7m18s
  kube-system                 etcd-minikube                                          0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         7m24s
  kube-system                 kube-apiserver-minikube                                250m (6%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         7m24s
  kube-system                 kube-controller-manager-minikube                       200m (5%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         7m24s
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-pgh7p                                       0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         7m18s
  kube-system                 kube-scheduler-minikube                                100m (2%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         7m24s
  kube-system                 storage-provisioner                                    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         7m24s
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests    Limits
  --------           --------    ------
  cpu                650m (16%)  0 (0%)
  memory             70Mi (0%)   170Mi (1%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                    From        Message
  ----     ------                   ----                   ----        -------
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  7m33s (x5 over 7m34s)  kubelet     Node minikube status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    7m33s (x4 over 7m34s)  kubelet     Node minikube status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     7m33s (x4 over 7m34s)  kubelet     Node minikube status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    7m24s                  kubelet     Node minikube status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   NodeAllocatableEnforced  7m24s                  kubelet     Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  7m24s                  kubelet     Node minikube status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   Starting                 7m24s                  kubelet     Starting kubelet.
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     7m24s                  kubelet     Node minikube status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
  Normal   NodeReady                7m24s                  kubelet     Node minikube status is now: NodeReady
  Normal   Starting                 7m17s                  kube-proxy  Starting kube-proxy.
  Warning  ContainerGCFailed        4m22s                  kubelet     rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = grpc: trying to send message larger than max (17408575 vs. 16777216)
  Normal   NodeNotReady             80s                    kubelet     Node minikube status is now: NodeNotReady
  Warning  ContainerGCFailed        19s (x4 over 3m21s)    kubelet     rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = grpc: trying to send message larger than max (31323462 vs. 16777216)
```

Comment: Did you create minikube cluster using docker as driver?

Comment: @slashpai No, VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be resource issue for docker runtime on minikube node. Check the [docker stats](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats) from minikube node. You may want to allocate more resources for your [minikube](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats) cluster